# Can't upload file using express-fileupload

Tags: node.js, express, post, file-upload, axios

I'm using express-fileupload module to parse uploaded file.
Upload is done with axios.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", data.gameCover);
formData.append("gameTitle", data.gameTitle);
formData.append("gamePrice", data.gamePrice);
formData.append("description", data.description);

return axios.post(apiUrl + "/games/add", formData).then(res => {
  dispatch({ type: ADD_GAME, payload: res.data.game });
});
```

[This is the POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HojvI.png)

Serverside code looks like this:

```
router.use(fileUpload());

router.post("/add", (req, res) => {
  if (!req.files) return res.status(400).send("No files were uploaded.");
```

Of course I'm getting "No files were uploaded" when trying to upload.

Comment: There is missing code on your snippet, this is only checking if there are files uploaded. You have a full example here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload#full-example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally after debugging step after step found that data.gameCover is an array
so that's the solution

```
formData.append("file", data.gameCover[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can optionaly use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) for handling multipart/formdata. 
you can then get the uploaded file as follows

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.diskStorage(
{destination: (req, file, cb)=>{
    cb(null, path.join(__dirname, '../uploads'));
  },
filename: (req, file, cb)=>{
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
});
let upload = multer({storage: storage});

// access the uploaded file with your route handler
router.post('/upload',upload.single('file'), (req, res, next)=> {
  if(req.file){
    //you can access your uploaded file
  }
});
```

Comment: I've already tried this method. Everything done exactly like in your's example and getting req.file undefined

Comment: check if you are uploading the file correctly, try using postman and send a post request to your endpoint and attach the file to the body of your request

Comment: Yes, and I'm getting response "No file uploaded"

Comment: confirm if your express server is running on the specified port.

Comment: Yes it does run on specified port

Comment: Already got the image on req.files without multer middleware and by using Postman, however by doing the same thing with axios, I get undefined